# Implement a bootstrap collapse with twig loop

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twig

I am trying to implement a bootstrap collapse inside a collapse but it doesn't work very well.

This is my code;

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
{% for frame,value in object.getPortHierarchy() %}
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="heading-f-{{ frame }}">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse-f-{{ frame }}" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse-f-{{ frame }}">
                    Frame #{{ frame }}
                </a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapse-f-{{ frame }}" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading-f-{{ frame }}">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
                {% for slot,value in value %}
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="heading-s-{{ slot }}">
                            <h4 class="panel-title">
                                <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse-s-{{ slot }}" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse-s-{{ slot }}">
                                    Slot #{{ slot }}
                                </a>
                            </h4>
                        </div>
                        <div id="collapse-s-{{ slot }}" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading-s-{{ slot }}">
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                {% for port,value in value %}
                                    Port: {{ value }}</br>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                {% endfor %}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

But when clicking on slots inside frames, the frames close as well. I've double checked my `IDs` and the correct numbers, but the issue still remain

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because you have the same id `#accordion` , but id should be unique

```
{#THE FIRST ID#}    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
{% for frame,value in object.getPortHierarchy() %}
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="heading-f-{{ frame }}">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse-f-{{ frame }}" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse-f-{{ frame }}">
                    Frame #{{ frame }}
                </a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapse-f-{{ frame }}" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading-f-{{ frame }}">
            <div class="panel-body">
        {#HERE#}        <div class="panel-group" id="accordion-{{frame}}" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
                {% for slot,value in value %}
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="heading-s-{{ slot }}">
                            <h4 class="panel-title">
                    {#HERE#}            <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-{{frame}}" href="#collapse-s-{{ slot }}" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse-s-{{ slot }}">
                                    Slot #{{ slot }}
                                </a>
                            </h4>
                        </div>
                        <div id="collapse-s-{{ slot }}" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading-s-{{ slot }}">
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                {% for port,value in value %}
                                    Port: {{ value }}</br>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                {% endfor %}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
</div>
```